# Table view cell is overlapped by navigator bar

Tags: swift

I have embedded navigation controller and created a table view controller. I have problem when running this in simulator. The top of table view cell is hidden by navigation bar. However, it works well after I go to next page and return back.

[image: navigation bar overlap table cell]

Comment: You could add some layout constraints?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44,0,0,0);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It would be useful to offer a little explanation as to why this may work.

Comment: It works. However when I change page and come back to this table view, the top cell is being displayed below the navigation bar 44px.